# How to move data from root disk to SAN in Solaris Zones

Tags: virtualization, solaris-10, san

Okay, this might be quite straight forward but since I have never done this before, I am not sure the ramifications. So I thought I ask here.

I have previosuly created a zone on an ldom (guest ldom at that) and palced the root fs of the zone on the ldom's root disk, because it was the only available space at the time. Now, the storage people acquired additional storage and granted the initially requested 30GB space for the zone. Zone's current footprint on the ldom's root disk is about 15 GB.

I created the zpool and zfs using the newly presented volume of storage. Now I need to move the zone data onto this zfs volume. And the zfs volume will not be shared with any other zone or entity whatsoever. It is dedicated.

Will a simple copy suffice, of course after shutting down the zone, such as:

```
cp -rp /my/zone/tree/zonename/root  /my/zone/tree/new-dedicated-temp-dir/
cp -rp /my/zone/tree/zonename/dev   /my/zone/tree/new-dedicated-temp-dir/
cp -rp /my/zone/tree/zonename/lu    /my/zone/tree/new-dedicated-temp-dir/

rm -r /my/zone/tree/zonename   

mv /my/zone/tree/new-dedicated-temp-dir   /my/zone/tree/zonename
```

and then bringing the zone back up

Will this work ? Or do I need to do something different and/or in addition to the above list of actions ?

Answer (score 1):

Moving the files in the zone's directory (zonepath) isn't sufficient. The Solaris zone system maintains information about zones outside that directory. The blessed procedure is [Solaris 10: Moving a Non-Global Zone](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/817-1592/gcgnc/index.html).